# Sorting a list of coordinates based on x-axis

Tags: r

Well, I am new to R.  what I want is plot a graph, I have the data for my x-axis and y-axis. Now I have a list of coordinates, I want to plot them in the graph, but before that I want to sort the the list of coordinates according to the data for x-axis only, and how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example portion of your data?

Comment: x=c(7,34,16,233,15,6,...)  y=c(476,388,372,666,403,368,...), now i want to sort them according to my x values (asend or desend). any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since you have your points as vectors, you can just plot them like this:

`plot(x, y)`

You don't need to sort them before plotting, but if you're sorting for another reason, first put them into a `data.frame` because you don't want to sort one vector without the other:

`data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)`

Then use the `order` function to sort. For ascending:

`data <- data[order(data$x), ]`

For descending:

`data <- data[rev(order(data$x)), ]`

Comment: what about I want to plot a line?

Comment: Add the `type="l"` argument to the `plot`, like this: `plot(x, y, type="l")`. You should read the help file for `plot` for similar simple adjustments.

Comment: thank you, i used lines(data$x,data$y). BTW, how to change the scale of y say, 50,100,150. Now i want to 50,75,100,125,150.